# Apache not recognise php [buildroot]

Tags: php, apache, buildroot

So I choosed apache in buildroot with php but I have a problem with interpreting php . I don't have module php in /usr/modules so I can't to add LoadModule to httpd.conf

In php.ini I have set:

```
; Enable the PHP scripting language engine under Apache.
; http://php.net/engine
engine = On
```

Under my apache config:
[httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/0egfiJzv)

Output http://192.168.2.103/index.php:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` in mime_module perhaps ?

Comment: Would the manual [Be any use to you](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php)

Comment: Added line `application/x-httpd-php .php` to /etc/mime.types but still not working fine

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I read this web but not work. 
Added ``--with-apxs2=$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/bin/apxs \`` in php.mk and ``--enable-so \`` in apache.mk.
I can't found libphp7.so in modules/.

Comment: Ok. Problem was in buildroot. It seems to me there is a bug. I issue instructions ``make apache-dirclean``, ``make php-dirclean`` and ``make all``. Thanks all.